# Добавление новой записи

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Имеется Windows Form приложение с подключенной БД. Там есть 3 таблицы Документ Исполнитель и исполнитель документа. Исполнитель документа это таблица для разбития связи многие ко многим. там 2 внешних ключа документа и исполнителя.

Нужно, чтобы при добавлении документа можно была добавить исполнителей документа. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче сама спросила, сама ответила. Нужно использовать `ListBox` и `SelectedItems`.

Cсылки с ответами:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059957/multi-selection-list-box-in-winforms
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420514/listbox-selected-items-in-winform